# What is the best GNU screen "taskbar" you've used/seen?

Tags: taskbar, gnu-screen

As some of you may know, screen offers an ability to have a "taskbar"-like bar that is always present and helps navigating around windows, etc. I find this bar irreplaceable.

**What is the best configuration you've seen or one that you think is the most optimal/useful?**

Mine is described and explained here: [Supercharge Your GNU Screen With A Power "Taskbar" And Never Feel Lost Again](http://beerpla.net/2009/10/06/supercharge-your-gnu-screen-with-a-power-taskbar-and-never-feel-lost-again/)

[image: screen powerbar]

Comment: It is worth comparing the OPs website as listed in his profile with the link above.

Comment: dmckee, yeah, that's why I said mine is described there.

Answer (score 19):

Here is mine:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{b kw}%H %{r}%1` %{w}| %{g}%c %{w}| %{y}%d.%m.%Y %{w}| %{g}%l %{w}| %{-b kw}%u %-Lw%{= rW}%50> %n%f %t %{-}%+Lw%<"
```

[image]

host | time | date | load average | obligatory window

I am unable to remember where I got this hardstatus or if I adapt it from an existing one.

Answer (score 4):

This is mine.

Screencopy: (missing bold+underline of current window.

```
 0-bash  1 bash  2 bash  4 irssi                 ~100%/54C ons 07 oktober  1:48
```

Code

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{+r} %-w%{+bu I}%n-%t%{-}%+w %= %{+ b}%11` %{-}%D %d %LM %{+b I}%c "
```

The backtick program returns the information `~` (on AC power) `100%` (battery) `54C` (temperature)

Comment: If I had a laptop, that battery indicator would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Here's mine:

[image: My status line]

The code for it:

```
backtick 1 5 1 screen-status-display
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{= gk}| %H | %{+b .y}%l%{-} | %D %M %d %C | %{+b g}%t (%n)%{-} |%1`"
```

The backtick script fills the last four status areas. They are:

1. Progress on ripping CDs
2. Build manual process is running (a long running task that I like to know when it's done)
3. What aptitude and kin are doing (flags are `aptd` (aptitude), `dpkg`, `dnld` (aptitude is downloading), and `apt`)
4. Indicator of how many tasks I currently have waiting for me (if more than three, the asterisks move back and forth).

Answer (score 3):

I use byobu and the default looks great
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, I just use `ctrl-a+"` to get the interactive menu of windows, or `ctrl-a+'` if I know the name of the one I want to jump to.  I'd rather no waste a line of realestate to show information that most of the time is useless to me.