# Is there any way to turn off the white bars in GNU Screen?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, gnu-screen

I am using the screen curses window manager and I want to know if it is possible to change the color of, or disable the white bars that appear between splits?

Comment: Can someone tag this curses/ncurses? I don't have enough points to make the tag.

Comment: Max of 5 tags, and gnu-screen is probably a better tag since `screen` ends up with a lot of LCD questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the command `caption string '<format>'`.

You can use [string escapes](http://aperiodic.net/screen/string_escapes).

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/51988/what-is-the-best-gnu-screen-taskbar-youve-used-seen) has several links on how to change the screen appear, which links to this [article](http://beerpla.net/2009/10/06/supercharge-your-gnu-screen-with-a-power-taskbar-and-never-feel-lost-again/) as the question starter.